# UDF optimization in Hadoop

Tags: performance, optimization, hadoop, apache-pig

I testing my UDF on Windows virtual machine with 8 cores and 8 GB RAM. I have created 5 files of 2 GB about and run the pig script after modifying "mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum".
The following runtime and statistics:

mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum = 2

`duration = 20 min 54 sec`

mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum = 4

`duration = 13 min 38 sec and about 30 sec for task`

`35% better`

mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum = 8

`duration = 12 min 44 sec and about 1 min for task`

`only 7% better`

Why such a small improvement when changing settings? any ideas? Job was divided into 145 tasks.

![4 slots][1]

![8 slots][2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of observations:

1. I imagine your windows machine only has a single disk backing this VM - so there is a limit to how much data you can read off disk at any one time (and write back for the spills). By increasing the task slots, your effectively driving up the read / write demands on your disk (and a more disk thrashing too potentially). If you have multiple disks backing your VM (and not virtual disks all on the same physical disk, i mean virtual disks backed by different physical disks), you would probably see a performance increase over what you've already seen.
2. By adding more map slots, you've reduced the amount of assignment waves that the Job Tracker needs to do - and each wave has a polling overhead (TT polling the jobs, JT polling the TTs and assigning new tasks to free slots). A 2 slot TT vs 8 slot TT will mean that you have 145/2=~73 assignment waves (if all tasks ran in equal time - obviously not realistic) vs 145/8=~19 waves - thats a ~3x increase in the amount of polling needed to be done (and it all adds up).

Comment: Today I repeated the test on the local windows machine (not virtual) with a local disk and got the same results. On the local machine, I can't improve the result?

Comment: The point is you need more disks to aid the throughput of your job, at some stage adding more task slots (cores) will tail off as you're limited by the disk read speed

Answer (score 0):

`mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` configures the maximum number of map tasks that will be run simultaneously by a task tracker. There is a practical hardware limit to how many tasks a single node can run at a time. So there will be diminishing returns when you keep increasing this number.

For example, say the tasktracker node has 8 cores. Say 4 cores are being used by processes other than the tasktracker. That leaves 4 cores for the mapred tasks. So your task time will improve from `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` = `1` to `4`, but after that, it would just remain static because the other tasks will just be waiting. In fact, if you increase it too much, the contention and context switching might make it slower. The [recommended value](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/tuning-dse-hadoop-map-reduce) for this parameter is the `No. of CPU cores - 1`